# How to add custom post type to nav_menu in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, post, menu, admin

I have a question.

I use the new `custom menus` of Wordpress 3.0. And I'm wondering how can I add custom post types to the menu. For now, I can just add `Pages` and `Categories`.

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The function [register_post_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) takes an argument `show_in_nav_menus`. If you set this to `TRUE` you get a selector for your custom post type in the menu manager.

#### Sample code

```
    register_post_type(
        'post_type_name'
    ,   array (
            'can_export'          => TRUE
        ,   'exclude_from_search' => FALSE
        ,   'has_archive'         => TRUE
        ,   'hierarchical'        => TRUE
        ,   'label'               => 'CPT Test'
        ,   'menu_position'       => 5
        ,   'public'              => TRUE
        ,   'publicly_queryable'  => TRUE
        ,   'query_var'           => 'cpttest'
        ,   'rewrite'             => array ( 'slug' => 'cpt-test' )
        ,   'show_ui'             => TRUE
        ,   'show_in_menu'        => TRUE
        ,   'show_in_nav_menus'   => TRUE
        ,   'supports'            => array ( 'editor', 'title' )
        )
    );
```

[image: Screen shot]

Screen shot with the custom post type named **CPT Test**.

Comment: can you please explain what is the value of the variable $this->post_type as I have used the same code and my custom post name is not appearing in the screen option.

Comment: @MusaddiqKhan It is the name of the post type. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I will check my code for other errors.

Comment: @MusaddiqKhan Make sure the box is not disabled in the **Screen Options**. Happened to me one time. :)